# Does not show the upload button

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, scrolltop

In my body I have:

```
html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}
```

With Jquery I want to put a button to go up

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var desplazamiento = $(this).scrollTop();
        var control = $('#scrolltop');

        if(desplazamiento > 100 && control.css('display') == 'none') {
                control.fadeIn();
        }

        if(desplazamiento < 100 && control.css('display') == 'block') {
                control.fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#scrolltop').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                return false;
        });
    });
```

With this style

```
#scrolltop {
    background-image: url("/pictures/arrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    bottom: 20px;
    display: none;
    height: 90px;
    left: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 17px 17px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: auto;
    width: 70px;
    z-index: 90;
}
```

And it does not show the button after looking for information the problem is 100% of the height of the body, I have read that you have to put another selector, not the window, so I put it in the section

```
$("section").scroll(function() {
```

But still don't show the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the selector that had to put was "body"

```
$("body").scroll(function() {
```

Is working!!